# Advantage to use HTML5 elements vs custom

Tags: css, html

I'm originally an iOS and mobile engineer and recently, I've been getting back into web development. In an attempt to dive as deep as I can into it, I've learned as much as about things like Webpack, more advanced SCSS, React, Redux, etc. After all my research, I'm still left with one burning question.

Why should I use HTML, specifically HTML5, elements in my markup vs creating all custom elements (such as a header using `div`s not `header`, wrapping dates in `<time />`, `nav` elements, etc). As an iOS engineer, I often find that design requirements make me build custom views with little to none built in view components and if I do, they're often my own components I've built from `UIView`s (equivalent to `div`, ish). In web development, unlike mobile, there are so many [built in elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/) and I assume there's reason for that.

To ask it another way:

1) Are there specific performance advantages to integrating more HTML5 elements into my markup?

2) Are the advantages purely semantic? That is to say does using the built in elements more provide my website with better semantics and readability at first glance?

3) Is there an accessibility advantage to using built in elements?

It seems that this would be the primary reason to use HTML5 elements. Supporting accessibility is really just an extension of good user experience and that's always worth implementing.

4) If I do use HTML5 standard elements more, wouldn't that introduce some risk into my projects?

By risk I mean introducing unintended behavior. If I use a all `divs` and only `divs` in my markup, I have predictable element behavior across the board, especially when it comes to styling. All divs are equal in that respect. If I use a HTML5 element that I haven't read up on fully, would I not risk injecting unwanted (not necessarily harmful though) behavior?

Comment: (1) Maybe, that would likely depend on the rendering engine and styling applied.  (2) There are semantic advantages.  And semantics are very important.  Remember that *other people* need to be able to understand your code.  (3) Yes.  (4)  No, why would it?  (All) This really sounds entirely opinion-based.  What you're essentially asking is, "Why should I use a particular tool when I can just do everything manually?"

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: To build on @Paulie_D's comment: most of the answers to this question will include some form of "should", "the prevailing opinion", "experts contend" and similar things. It's not a *bad* question per se, it's just [not quite on topic for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Fair enough, is there anywhere else that you can recommend me to then?

Comment: I also only sort of agree that this is opinion based. If you note, I'm asking about performance advantages, accessibility, and UX, not which should I do, more what are concrete engineering reasons for doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your point and I have never really put much thought into this. However after looking through some articles and sources the general consensus is that there is no evidence that using custom elements causes any performance issue's over the standard HTML elements. However there is a few sources that say stick to some sort of guide line for the purpose of semantics correctness.

**Are there specific performance advantages to integrating more HTML5 elements into my markup?**

1) Not particularly, there is hardly any performance problems with markup that I have run into on multiple platforms.

**Are the advantages purely semantic? That is to say does using the built in elements more provide my website with better semantics and readability at first glance?**

2) Yes and no. Following the HTML5 element markup does make it easier for other developers to find a bug or to refactor the markup at some point down the line. And no HTML isn't purely for the semantic side of things although semantics do make things easier in a verity of different ways, in terms of SEO and how the browser reads the site for screen readers is vitally important to creating a fully accessible site on the web.

**Is there an accessibility advantage to using built in elements?**

3) HTML5 makes creating accessible sites easier for two main reasons: semantics and ARIA. The new (some currently available) HTML headings like `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<aside>`, etc. allow screen readers to easily access content. Before, your screen readers had no way to determine what a given `<div>` was even if you assigned it an ID or Class.

**If I do use HTML5 standard elements more, wouldn't that introduce some risk into my projects?**

4) I haven't come across this myself so I have no experience on this potential problem.

I would say if you want go for it, but keep in mind the advantages of using mainly HTML5 element's and the disadvantages of using custom element's. I personally most of the time use completely standard HTML5 element's but sometimes I might use my own custom element's for a situation that seems it would benefit from such as makes better semantic sense to write my own element for it versus using an element that might cause confusing later down the line to me and other developer's.

Comment: Alright that all makes sense. I think what you said in #2, about being easier for SEO, etc is primarily what I was looking for. Not to mention maintainability which you talked about in #1. Thanks for the answers

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)